# Static max/min width for an img of arbitrary size

Tags: html, css, image

The `max-` and `min-width` attributes on an `<img>` tag are very useful, particularly the max width which can prevent an img from streching larger than its original size.

Now this is easy when you are using a specific image, so you can set it to be the same as the size of the image. But what if you want to apply this to a general image, for example one which is uploaded by a user? (so you don't know what the dimensions are) In other words, set the max/min width to the exact dimension of the image, for an arbitrary image.

Comment: If the image was uploaded to you, then you *do* know what the dimensions are. [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/getimagesize).

Comment: Yes but I need the css to be arbitrary, for an uploaded image of *any size*

Comment: And by the way I'm not using PHP @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: Then how are you accepting file uploads?

Comment: Could be using another server side lang ? :S

Comment: I am working with theme-based CSS files so I need a CSS-only solution, thank you

Comment: @MarcoPrins In order to preserve the aspect ratio of the image, you will need to constrain the image by either its height or its width.. not both. We don't know much about the structure of your HTML at the moment, or how you would like the uploaded image(s) presented on the page so we cannot help you.

Comment: I am constraining only by width

Comment: @MarcoPrins Dynamically setting the max width value based on the dimensions of a specific image is not possible in CSS alone, especially because CSS files are external files and as such, changes to them cannot be made to them as this would present a security threat to the file system. If I was you I would put the image in a containing div and set its width to an arbitrary value, whether it be a percentage of the page or a fixed pixel value. Another solution of course could be to have some sort of hidden field on the page which holds the width of the image as written to it from the server side

Answer (score 0):

this should do it...

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
</script>
...
<div id="img-container"></div>
...
</html>
<script>
function loadImage(imgSrc) {
    var newImg = new Image();

    newImg.onload = function() {
      var height = newImg.height;
      var width = newImg.width;
      $(newImg).css({
        'max-width':width,
        'max-height':height
      });
      $("#img-container").append(newImg);
    }

    newImg.src = imgSrc; // this must be done AFTER setting onload
}

loadImage('youimage.jpg');

</script>
```

you could also use server side code to get the image size.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#file").change(function(e) {
var file, img;
if ((file = this.files[0])) {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
    };
    img.onerror = function() {
        alert( "not a valid file: " + file.type);
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);

}

});
```

**Working demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/4N6D9/1/